# Web Application health check

Tags: bash, shell, automation

We are in process of automating the health check of a web application.
The main steps that are performed are:-

- URL accessibility - ping host name or wget or curl
- Response time - Check manually via browser network tabs
- Error rate - manual count of errors occurred
- Data/Link validation - Manually download a file or click links to go and check the child pages or if API is exposed, browse to the API link
- Perform end-to-end flow - manually iterate through the web ui.

However, we are trying to automate these via IPautomata.
One way would be to run the same host commands that were previously done manually.
Any suggestions as how we can do them better? or how can we automate these steps via a shell script which we can run as a command step

PS: we would like to use **IPautomata** for automation

Comment: what commands you are using to check above things manually ?

Comment: I do not have commands for each of the actions, e.g. to check the response time i have to take help of the browser , similarly for data/link validation i need to manually click/download the links on the UI

Comment: till now this is what i have come up with;curl "https://my.org.com/org/" -s -o /dev/null -w \
"response_code: %{http_code}\n
dns_time: %{time_namelookup}
connect_time: %{time_connect}
pretransfer_time: %{time_pretransfer}
starttransfer_time: %{time_starttransfer}
total_time: %{time_total}
"